# Detecting mod_php7 in Apache 2.4 .htaccess fails

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4, mod-php

Consider the following `.htaccess` directives:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    Define PHP_ENABLED
</IfModule>
<IfDefine !PHP_ENABLED>
    Require all denied
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine PHP_ENABLED>
    php_value expose_php    Off
</IfDefine>
```

It just dies with `403 Forbidden`.
I suppose it's because it does not detect `mod_php7`, or maybe the module has another name?

What's even worse is that I have set `ErrorDocument 403` in the same file (in docroot - before the php-check) - but this is also ignored - in the case stated above.

**more info:**
If I omit these directives above the output of `die(php_version());` from within PHP yields: `7.0.27-1~dotdeb+8.1`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Directive `Define` is not allowed in a htaccess context. (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#define).

So perhaps you can defined the `<IfModule  ..` part in the server context.